# Failed to build Clang 3.0 on windows XP， idenfifier "PSRWLOCK" not defined. Why?

Tags: windows, llvm, clang

I download the latest LLVM3.0 and Clang3.0 source, following the build instructions and finally get the VS solution file "LLVM.sln" and all the .vcproj files.

Then I build the libClang, but some errors ocurred when build project "LLVMSupport":
error C2065: “PSRWLOCK”: Undefined identifier

the problem located at RWMutex.cpp which include "Windows/RWMutex.inc".
in the file "RWMutex.inc" I notice a block of code:

```
// Windows has slim read-writer lock support on Vista and higher, so we
// will attempt to load the APIs.  If they exist, we will use them, and
// if not, we will fall back on critical sections.  When we drop support
// for XP, we can stop lazy-loading these APIs and just use them directly.
#if defined(__MINGW32__)
// Taken from WinNT.h
typedef struct _RTL_SRWLOCK {
    PVOID Ptr;
} RTL_SRWLOCK, *PRTL_SRWLOCK;

// Taken from WinBase.h
typedef RTL_SRWLOCK SRWLOCK, *PSRWLOCK;
#endif
...
```

what does it mean? should I define a "**MINGW32**" even if I'm using a Microsoft C++ compiler?

Comment: No, it means you should indicate that you're targeting Vista and later: `#define WINVER _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439752/what-is-winver) for details.

Comment: they didn't test under VS2005? Look at:http://groups.google.com/group/llvm-dev/browse_thread/thread/a01869c14dc9f45a/487bb2dc40fed26f?show_docid=487bb2dc40fed26f#

Comment: That has nothing to do with VS 2005. The target Windows version isn't necessarily Vista on newer versions, and it can be easily specified in VS 2005.

Comment: And yes, LLVM isn't officially supporting VS 2005.

Comment: Sorry the title is not good. it's about SDK version other than OS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, VC2005 does not support standard C++ pretty well to compile llvm/clang. We saw many problems in past. So, it is advised to use VC2008/VC2010 instead.

Comment: concretely what kind of problem? runtime errors?I have build LLVM-2.9 with VS2005. I have to use VS2005 now. :-(