# Visual Studio C++ filtering code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've got the Version API Helper functions running and that lets me do x if in y but how is it I set Visual Studio to ignore code if the target operating system does not support it, the issue being:

```
 ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx
```

I need it for Windows 7 and above but when compiling the application the function gets included so wont run on XP.

Comment: Are you looking for `WINVER`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439752/what-is-winver

Comment: No, I'm looking to be able to have the function ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx in my project but only be loaded if os => Win 7 but as is the function gets included in the compiled .exe list of functions and stops the .exe running on XP

Comment: ... use `#ifdef` on some symbol to conditionally compile code. You can even decide based on the value of some symbol (like `WINVER`). See [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for some info. This is at *compile time*, though, and if I understand your comment, you want it at run-time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use explicit linking, using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get a function pointer to ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx.  That way the call is not compiled into your code but it is conditionally executed by your code.