# MinGW DEVMODE Constant Error

Tags: c++, windows, dev-mode

experts! I'm a WinXP user in a Virtual Machine. I have installed MinGW and an IDE for develop C/C++ applications. Today I encountered a code snippet, at MSDN as you can see,

```
DEVMODE dm;
   // initialize the DEVMODE structure
   ZeroMemory(&dm, sizeof(dm));
   dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

   if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
   {
      // swap height and width
      DWORD dwTemp = dm.dmPelsHeight;
      dm.dmPelsHeight= dm.dmPelsWidth;
      dm.dmPelsWidth = dwTemp;

      // determine new orientaion
      switch (dm.dmDisplayOrientation)
      {
      case DMDO_DEFAULT:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_270;
         break;
      case DMDO_270:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_180;
         break;
      case DMDO_180:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_90;
         break;
      case DMDO_90:
         dm.dmDisplayOrientation = DMDO_DEFAULT;
         break;
      default:
         // unknown orientation value
         // add exception handling here
         break;
      }
      long lRet = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0);
      if (DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL != lRet)
      {
         // add exception handling here
      }
   }
```

When I compile that snippet in my sample, I got this error message,

> error: 'DMDO_DEFAULT' undeclared
>
> error: 'DMDO_270' undeclared
>
> ..
>
> error: 'DMDO_90' undeclared

I know that these constants included in "wingdi.h" file, in my case this file contains this code, i think that it is correct.

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0501)
..
#define DMDO_DEFAULT 0x00000000
#define DMDO_90 0x00000001
#define DMDO_180 0x00000002
#define DMDO_270 0x00000003
```

So where is the problem, can anyone explain to me? "ver" command gave me that output,

```
$ ver
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
```

Sorry for my English grammar, thank you for help me.

Comment: Related: [What is WINVER?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439752/464709)

Comment: Thank you so much, @FrédéricHamidi. This comment is my solution. But, why it won't declared automaticly?

Comment: Visual Studio declares it automatically in the `stdafx.h` file it generates when you create a new project. But you're using MinGW, so...

Comment: Oh, I'm thankful to you.